# StartListening() didn't work in OnBindviewHolder or in the onStart() method. Issue with Android Studio 3.4 version

Tags: java, android

startListening() in onBindviewHolder didn't work and also not work in onStart() method.

After commented this line show MainAcitvity but not the posts items in this activity. If i requested to add in onStart() method it show red hot line.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private RecyclerView postlist;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
    private TextView NavProfileUserName;
    private ImageButton AddNewPostButton;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef, PostsRef;
    String currentUserID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        AddNewPostButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_new_post_button);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        postlist = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.all_users_post_list);
        postlist.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        postlist.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
        NavProfileImage = (CircleImageView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
        NavProfileUserName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_name);

        UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname")) {
                        String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                        NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                    }

                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User doesnot Exist here...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                UserMenuSelector(item);
                return false;
            }
        });

        AddNewPostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendUserToPostActivity();
            }
        });

        DisplayAllUsersPosts();
    }

    private void DisplayAllUsersPosts() {

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>().setQuery(PostsRef, Posts.class).build();
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {
                holder.username.setText(model.getFullname());
                holder.time.setText(" " + model.getTime());
                holder.date.setText(" " + model.getDate());
                holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileimage()).into(holder.user_post_image);
                Picasso.get().load(model.getPostimage()).into(holder.postImage);

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, parent, false);
                PostsViewHolder viewHolder = new PostsViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        //firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        postlist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView username, date, time, description;
        CircleImageView user_post_image;
        ImageView postImage;

        public PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_Description);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            user_post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_image);
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToPostActivity() {
        Intent postIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
        startActivity(postIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        } else {
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistence() {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id)) {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity() {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_post:
                SendUserToPostActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_friend:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Find Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_messages:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Messages", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                mAuth.signOut();
                SendUserToLoginActivity();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> 04-19 12:10:05.836 4162-4162/androidwork.app.chadii.socialchatapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: androidwork.app.chadii.socialchatapp, PID: 4162
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at androidwork.app.chadii.socialchatapp.MainActivity$4.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:165)
>           at androidwork.app.chadii.socialchatapp.MainActivity$4.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:150)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>           at
>
> ## ERROR_HERE
>
> androidwork.app.chadii.socialchatapp.MainActivity$4.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:165) 
>           at androidwork.app.chadii.socialchatapp.MainActivity$4.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:150) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888) 
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_CENTER not supported.
>           at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setScaleType(CircleImageView.java:134)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:169)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:135)
>           at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.(CircleImageView.java:98)
>           at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.(CircleImageView.java:94)

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ScaleType FIT_CENTER not supported. at de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.setScaleType(CircleImageView.java:134)
```

CircleImageView only support ScaleType.CENTER_CROP

link https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/src/main/java/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/CircleImageView.java

```
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;
...
@Override
public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
    }
}
...
```

Comment: this is valid but it's not the answer of my problem

Comment: @Bablu Can you share your XML for all_posts_layout.xm?

Comment: My problem solve later error not in XML file error in model class constructor only that's only give the app crashes... @fancyjy thanx